# How two cars are getting at the same point of the road (obstacle, cyclist, another car parked on a small part of the road) in the same time?

Tags: everyday-life, velocity

You have an ordinary road, two ways. You are driving on the right part of the road and you see a person walking on the same part 400m away, you have to slow down or to accelerate because from the other way is coming another car. What I always see in this situation is this: if you are going to maintain the same speed, the opposite direction car is going to meet with you exactly where the person is, exactly at the obstacle. Can this be explained by physics?

Thanks guys! Maybe for most of the people around here this seems simple but I want to know more about this.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with physics. There is no physical law that says that two objects will meet at an intervening obstacle if they keep the same speed. If anything, this is a perceived problem and not a real one and has more to do with psychology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the pedestrian relative to the two cars when they meet will depend on the speed of each car, the initial distance between the pedestrian and the other car as well as yours, and to a lesser extent on how fast the pedestrian is walking assuming the speeds of the cars is much greater than the pedestrian.

Considering all the variables I don’t see how you can always meet the other car exactly where the pedestrian is.

Hope this helps